# Do I need to take my luggage when on a transit visa?

Tags: luggage, transit-visas, dxb

I have my flight from Orlando, United States to Dubai and from Dubai to Mumbai, India. I booked a multi-destination flight, so I can stay in Dubai for 12 hours and go out of the airport. I will get a transit visa upon arrival in Dubai. It’s the same airline all the way.

Do I need to take my checked bags at the Dubai airport?

Comment: Do you have a single ticket ORD-DXB-BOM or you have two separate tickets?

Comment: On two separate tickets you must always get your luggage.  On a single ticket, it will depend on the transit procedure at DXB (at some airports like YYC, you don't get your baggage anymore except when requested by customs and immigration officers, but at most, you do).

Comment: If you're on a single booking with Emirates then they will transfer your luggage.

Answer (score 1):

Normally if you booked this multi-city itinerary as a single ticket, then your baggage will be checked all the way through to its final destination. So that you will not have to take your luggage out, nor will you have the opportunity to do do unless you ask the agent to *short-check* the bag.

Now, if you booked it as multiple tickets (some third-party sites do that for you), you will have multiple tickets and then you must check where each one starts and ends. If you arrival to Dubai and departure are on the same ticket, then your baggage can go all the way.

Comment: 12 hours is such a time that some people will request their luggage. So do check with the people who take your bag at your departure airport whether they do (can) send your luggage on for you.

Comment: That's why I mentioned short-checking. By default though that is not the case.